# From SQL table find the same product have same product key

Tags: sql, monetdb

I have table in the following structure, I need to write SQL to find the product having multiple product keys? Can anyone please help to write the SQL?

| Product | Product Key |
| --- | --- |
| First | 10 |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 2 |
| Second | 2 |
| Third | 3 |
| Four | 3 |
| Test | 5 |
| Test | 5 |

Expected output would be

| Product |
| --- |
| First |
| Third |
| Four |

Comment: Why `Test` is excluded from expected outcome and not `First`?

Comment: I guess you just forgot to put Test in your output?

If you want the name of the different product, use DISTINCT.

SELECT DISTINCT product FROM productFile

Comment: First product key is referred in second also, but Test is not referred in another product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get using syntax from SQL Server

```
SELECT Product
FROM Products
WHERE "Product Key" IN (
    SELECT "Product Key"
    FROM Products
    GROUP BY "Product Key"
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Product) > 1
)
GROUP BY Product;
```

These are the steps:

1. You have to search `product key` that contain multiple product.
2. We have `1` and `3`.
3. And then we get product that has product key = `1` and `3`.
4. Then, we will get this output:

[image]

This is [fiddle for sql server](https://dbfiddle.uk/AAcTllZC).

You can adjust it to monetdb syntax

Comment: Thanks bro for your help :)

I have one question in your input If I edit `  ('First', 1),
    ('First', 10),
    ('Second', 2),
    ('Second', 2),
    ('Third', 3),
    ('Four', 3),
    ('Test', 5),
    ('Test', 5);` then I need `First`, `Four`, `Third` also but I'm getting `Four` and `Third` only How I can rewrite your query?

Comment: Thanks bro for your help :) I have one question in your input If I edit ` ('First', 1), ('First', 10), ('Second', 2), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Four', 3), ('Test', 5), ('Test', 5);` then I need First, Four, Third also but I'm getting Four and Third only How I can rewrite your query? <<<It will get `Four` and `Third` only because `Product Key` =  `1`,`10`,`2` and `5` don't have multiple `Product`. Why you want `First` as output? Please explain the logic.

Comment: U did it :) bro thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT` in a `HAVING`, so it groups up by `Product` but then excludes anything which has only one `ProductKey`.

```sql
SELECT
  p.Product
FROM Products p
GROUP BY
  p.Product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.ProductKey) > 1;
```

A somewhat more efficient method, but less obvious:

```sql
HAVING MIN(p.ProductKey) <> MAX(p.ProductKey);
```

Comment: Hi Bro,
`INSERT INTO Products (Product, "Product Key")
VALUES
    ('First', 1),
    ('First', 10),
    ('Second', 2),
    ('Second', 2),
    ('Third', 3),
    ('Four', 3),
    ('Test', 5),
    ('Test', 5);` 
If this is your input then I need output as `First` ,`Third`, and `Four` also but from your query I'm getting only `First`

Comment: OK please explain the logic then. Why exclude `Test` and `Second` in that case? Also how does it make sense to have two completely identical rows, where is the database normalization?

Comment: `Second` and `Test` are referring one to one relation

`3` is product key is referring both `Third` and `Four`  

`First` is referring different keys

Comment: You need to be clearer. It originally sounded like you wanted only those `Product` which had multiple `ProductKey`. Now it sounds like you want all `Product` except those that have *multiple* rows with the same `ProductKey`?

Comment: I need the `Product` which have one -> one relation. 
One product can't be have multiple keys and Same Keys don't have multiple product also

Comment: But `First` has multiple keys so why are you including that? `Second` has the same key twice, why is that not included? **Please be clear on the steps and logic involved**

Comment: User can enter any data, as system we need to validate

Comment: That doesn't help me, ***Please be clear on the steps and logic involved*** as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause to include only products whose total keys equal their total unique keys:

```
SELECT Product
FROM Products
GROUP BY Product
HAVING COUNT(ProductKey) = COUNT(DISTINCT ProductKey);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9rkzSCA)

Comment: `COUNT(ProductKey)` and `COUNT(*)` should be the same assuming no nulls.

Comment: Bro your answer also bit not correct `('First', 1),     
  ('First', 10),     
  ('Second', 2),        
  ('Third', 3),     
  ('Four', 7),     
  ('Test', 5),     
  ('Test', 5);`
I tried this input but getting wrong result

Only `First` should come -> First only referring different key